# Python POST request getting json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I tried posting a request in Postman, worked fine and got the response. However while trying from python requests body of the response is empty. But the response status code is 200.
When I try to print response.json() I get the following error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError"
Also when I try to print response.text it is empty

The header of the post request is of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

My code :

```
resp = requests.post("myurl",data=request_json,headers=headers, verify=False)
       
code = resp.status_code
print("Status Code " + str(code))
print(resp.headers)
print("Test : "+resp.text)
print(resp.json())
```

My Output:

```
Status Code 200
{'date': 'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 10:51:51 GMT', 'server': 'qsad-cvfd', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '72', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
Test :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    test1()
  File "test.py", line 26, in test1
    print(resp.json())
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\analytica\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I Solve this issue ?

Comment: You've received null response from the server (judging by the `'Content-Length': '0'` response header).

Comment: But it works properly in Postman. That is why I am confused

Comment: You need to check the server logs or HTTP sniffer to see how your requests differ

Comment: Do you use `'Content-Length': '0'` in postman headers too ?

Comment: Agreed to @Amin. Why are you sending `'Content-Length' : '0'` in the headers?

Comment: No I am not sending anything as content-length. It seems it was bug! My code was correct though ! I am so sorry i wasted your time as well in this question. My apologies !